# I get an ERROR while installing cocoa pods

Tags: rubygems, cocoapods

I try to install cocoa pods on my Mac but I instantly get an ERROR.

I tried to install them with

```sh
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Entered my password and get the following ERROR.

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

please help me to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  gem sources -a https://rubygems.org/
  gem sources -u
  sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I did like you wrote and now I get these ERRORS: WARNING:  Unable to pull data from 'https://rubygems.org/': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Please, put the answer as correct if it was useful! Thanks!